# JSON to CSV conversion without schema in Hand

Tags: java, json

I am Trying to convert JSON data from a file to CSV,schema is dynamic and is available at run time from a file. How do i acheive this?

Comment: if you don't want the question to be closed as too broad, give an example input, expected output and at least a minimal effort you've made to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/). it is straightforward and concise yet feature rich.

1. Read the Schema from the JSON input and create a `CSVFormat` instance.  Take a look at the predefined `DEFAULT` and `EXCEL` static instances.  You use `withHeader(String... header)` to specify the schema fields.
2. Then you create a `CSVPrinter` instance.  You give it a `Writer` and the `CSVFormet` as ctor args.  (it is Closeable so you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)  to safely open the IO resource) and now write lines using the various print methods.